# Why does multithreading have a Lock object?

Tags: python, multithreading

My understanding is that [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) allows in reality to have only **one** thread active at a time, continously switching between threads. This is useful when having IO-bound operations where the worload is effectively offloaded somewhere else (an PI, a database, ...).

If so, **why is there a need for a [Lock()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object?** There is no risk that a variable is accessed by two threads simultaneously (as it can be the case in multiprocessing) so I fail to see a real usage for locks in this context.

Comment: Isn't the limitation of one thread only true for the CPython implementation? And the standard library has to be implemented by all potential Python interpreters? (e.g.: in Jython you would need the `Lock` object as it has "true" multithreading)

Comment: actually there is risk that a variable is accessed by two threads.

Comment: As with any processor, Pythons Virtual Machine has some atomic operations, but most Python statements are not atomic. Therefore locks.

Comment: The problems with concurrency come when you have to complete more than one operation atomically (which means: practically always). Keep in mind that even `a += 1` is more than one byte code: `LOAD_FAST a`, `LOAD_CONST 1`, `INPLACE_ADD`, `STORE_FAST a`. So there are *3* places where these instructions could be halted before they are completed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, locks secure whole areas, think of updating a file:

```
with lock:
    with open("some_file", "r+") as f:
        do_something(f)
```

Even single operations like

```
a['b'] += 1
```

might lead to multiple operations (read value of `a['b']`, increment, write to `a['b']`), and need to be secured by a lock:

```
with lock:
    a['b'] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I use locks for file access and my question was more about the in-memory data (variables). Your example of non-atomicity is very clear.

Answer (score 3):

*There is no risk that a variable is accessed by two threads simultaneously*

It depends on the scheduler used to implement multithreading. Context switches may occur on any interrupt no matter what the current thread does. Therefore a thread accessing a variable may be interrupted on a clock interrupt and another thread accessing the same variable may be activated.